# PHP function varying parameters

Tags: php, function, parameters

**I couldn't find about my issue on google and SO**. Hope, i can explain you.

You'll understand when looked following function:

```
function get_page($identity)
{
    if($identity is id)
       $page = $this->get_page_from_model_by_id($identity);
    elseif($identity is alias)
       $page = $this->get_page_from_model_by_alias($identity);
}
```

#### My used function:

```
get_page(5); // with id
or
get_page('about-us'); // with alias
or
get_page(5, 'about-us'); // with both
```

I want to send parameter to function `id` or `alias`. It should be only one identifier.

I dont want like `function get_page($id, $alias)`

How can i get and know parameter type with only one `variable`. Is there any function or it possible?

Comment: Are `id` and `alias` classes, and the param passed is object of that class?

Comment: `func_get_args()` return the given arguments as an array

Comment: `if($identity instanceof id)` ?

Comment: is_int($identity) shouldn't do it just fine?

Comment: can't you just call `get_page_from_model_by_id` and `get_page_from_model_by_alias` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(is_numeric($identity)) {
    $page = $this->get_page_from_model_by_id($identity);
}
elseif(is_string($identity)) {
    $page = $this->get_page_from_model_by_alias($identity);
}
elseif(func_num_args() === 2) {
    $id = func_get_arg(0);
    $alias = func_get_arg(1);
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I know `func_num_args`. I was searching function that give me the variable name/type directly. But it's ok. Btw i changed `is_int` to `is_numeric` because of i'm getting `identity` from uri and it's always string.

Comment: @Bora you should test in the opposite order then, because the number will probably evaluate to true if tested as a string. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

Use [is_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php) to find whether input is integer or character.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of **`func_get_args()`**

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "<br />\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
?>
```

**[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete solution:

```
function get_page()
{
    $alias = false;
    $id = false;
    foreach(func_get_args() as $arg)
        if(is_string($arg))
             $alias = $arg;
        else if(is_int($arg))
             $id = $arg;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming id is always a number, you could test for it with php's is_numeric()

```
function get_page($identity)
{
    if(is_numeric($identity) {
       $page = $this->get_page_from_model_by_id($identity);

    } else { 
       $page = $this->get_page_from_model_by_alias($identity);
    }
}
```